# How to display multiple calendar for list of object

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, calendar

Hello I have problem with mvc project. I need to make multiple calendar for workers(for each worker one calendar with the worker date). This is my code.

```
public JsonResult Index()
     {
        var employees = this.employeeManager.EmployeeList();
        var eventList = new List();
        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            var eventList = from e in employee.Mounts
                            select new
                            {
                                id = e.Id,
                                firstName = e.Name,
                                dateFrom = e.DateFrom,
                                dateTo = e.DateTo,
                            };
        }
        return Json(eventList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I need to display list of mount for each employee in their own calendar. This is my javascript code:

```
function GetEvents() {
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: "{}",
    url: "/Employee/Index",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: false,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: ''
            },
            defaultView: 'basicWeek',
            editable: true,
            events: $.map(data, function (item, i) {
                var event = new Object();
                event.start = moment(item.DateFrom).utc();
                event.end = moment(item.DateTo).utc();
                event.title = item.name;
                event.id = item.id;
                return event;
            }),
            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
                $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

            },
        });

    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#cal_error").text(errorThrown); //Handle Error
    }
});
}
```

How can I return in json object with list of objects?

Employee class:

```
public class EmployeeDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumer { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public MountDto[] Mounts { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

}
```

Mount class:

```
public class MountDto
{
    public long? Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Place { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: Can you please add us little more informations, like how your employee model and months model looks like?

Comment: I edit the main post

Comment: do you need one calendar control for each employee?

Comment: Yes, I need to show his own mount.

Comment: So I think you have to iterate through data and inside bind the calendar for each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer adds to the above answer. Iterate through your data in the client side code in order to create multiple calendar controls. Code below is not tested but it should work.

```
function GetEvents() {
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: "{}",
    url: "/Employee/Index",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        data.forEach(function(item)
       {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            theme: false,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: ''
            },
            defaultView: 'basicWeek',
            editable: true,
            events:  $.map(item.eventsList, function (currEvent, i) {
            var event = new Object();
            event.start = moment(currEvent.DateFrom).utc();
            event.end = moment(currEvent.DateTo).utc();
            event.title = currEvent.name;
            event.id = currEvent.id;
            return event;
        }),
            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
                $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

            },
        });  
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rewrite your query to return list of data grouped by employee id:

```
public JsonResult Index()
{
    var employees = this.employeeManager.EmployeeList();

    var employeesList = employees.Select(e => new 
                    {
                        id = e.Id,
                        firstName = e.Name,
                        eventsList = e.Months.Select(o => new {
                             id = o.Id,
                             firstName = o.Name,
                             dateFrom = o.DateFrom,
                             dateTo = o.DateTo
                        }).ToList()
                    }).ToList();

    return Json(employeesList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You also need to rewrite your client side code to iterate through returned data.

Comment: It will work when I have one mount in one employee, but i have much mount in one employee and i want to show it in calendar. For each employee one calendar with multiple mount.